# How to distribute n identical objects among r persons, such that everyone gets at least 1 object?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

1 object can be given to each of r persons in 1 way. Now left with n-1 objects. To distribute n-1 objects amongst r persons we need to create r-1 divisions in n-1 objects. Getting confused here.

Comment: Start by giving one object to each person. Then $n-r$ objects are left and much be divided over $r$ persons without any further constraints. Use stars and bars.

Comment: Surely there are $n-r$ objects left after each person gets one?

Comment: You can solve the problem directly by using [Theorem 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) or indirectly by using Theorem 2 on the linked page.